# How to set instance in attribute, using DI. ASP.NET vNext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have next code:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public BasicAuthenticationAttribute()
    {
         var appEnvironment = CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IApplicationEnvironment)) as IApplicationEnvironment;
         IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json").Build();
          UserName = configuration["UserName"];
          Password = configuration["UserPassword"];
    } 
}
public class PagesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("settings")]
    [BasicAuthentication] // I use it there
    public IActionResult Settings()
    {
         ...
    } 
}
```

This's attribute for basicAuth.
I need to inject "`IConfiguration configuration`" into my constructor, to read config json.

How can I get  IConfiguration into  my attribute? May be there is a service like `CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider` but for IConfiguration

PS I understand that Attribute values must be constants

Answer (score 0):

[Attribute values must be constants](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/12/12/more-c-attribute-annoyances/), so you will not be able to pass in an instance of a class.

Comment: Yes, You're right. May we get instance, using DI container?

Answer (score 0):

To use this in your attribute class:

```
[FromServices]
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
```

it must be public and has getter and setter, it will get the service from DI automaticly.